# How to the Change URL Patern so that it can access normal JSP also

Tags: web-services, servlets, cxf

This is my web.xml for my webservices developed using  Apache CXF project 
As a result of this url pattern , even if i want to access a small HTMl page using

```
http:localhost:8080/ZTWeb/Test.html
```

This si result in No Service Found ( As i guess  each and every request is being treated as Web service itself )

Please tell me how to resolve this , Means how can i access the HTML pages . JSP pages inside the web application

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the CXF Servlet to another location, for example `/services/*`